# Find source location where a branch was mispredicted

Tags: linux, branch, performancecounter, perf

I'm trying to find the positions in a function where branches are mispredicted most often. I gave perf a try, as follows:

`perf record ./a.out`

`a.out` was compiled with options `-ggdb -fno-omit-frame-pointer`, as recommended by the manual.

How can I find these spots?

Answer (score 0):

By default `perf record` performs sampling on [cycles](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record) event. Each time a given number of cycles events occured, a sample with different thing inside it (such as the instruction pointer) is recorded. With this you can mainly observe into which part of your code you spent your time.

The event you want to perform sampling on is specified with the -e option. May be you can try to specify the branch mispredicted event (according to your hardware) and samples will only be generated every X occurences for this event. But I am not sure sampling is possible for all the events.

I don't know what it really means, but on my perf version 3.11, the following option exists:

-j, --branch-filter
Enable taken branch stack sampling. Each sample captures a series of consecutive taken branches. The number of branches captured with each sample depends on the underlying
hardware, the type of branches of interest, and the executed code. It is possible to select the types of branches captured by enabling filters.

Comment: "-j" is LBR - Intel last branch record (list of N previous branches executed by CPU).  @user46317 needs `perf record -e branch-misses`, and most CPU events supports periodic sampling (with hardware generating perf interrupt every X events). I think, only uncore events cannot generate the perf interrupt, and may be only polled for current or total value.